# .htaccess non www to www not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

if i remove the rules for the non www to www and go to my site test.com it works fine, but as soon as I enable the rewriteengine on to change test.com to www.test i get server not found.

Please note I also ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and I get Module rewrite already enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have a DNS entry for `www.test.com`. You need to make sure that resolves to the same IP address as `test.com` does.

Comment: you mean create an A record for www.test.com with the same IP ?

Comment: @VarunSheth yeah, A or CNAME pointing to `test.com`, either one

Comment: @VarunSheth on my side i already have 'A Record' for www.domai.com with ip pointing to my website ip. but still its not working for me.